# Слияние mpeg ts чанков в несколько файлов большего размера

Tags: c#

Стоит задача объединить множество чанков mpeg ts в файлы объёмом по 5 ГБ
На входе 400 Гб чанков размером по ~6мб. Нужно объединить их в файлы размером по 5 Гб.
Имена чанков идут по возрастанию. Все они лежат в одной папке.
Нашёл решение как все чанки в отдельной папке слить в один файл, но вот как сделать чтобы программа сама делила выходные файлы по 5 гб не могу.

```
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path_with_ts);
        FileInfo[] Files = dir.GetFiles("*.ts", searchOption:SearchOption.AllDirectories);           

        string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.ss");
        string pathToSave = @"D:\chunks1\" + dateTime + ".ts";
        fs = new FileStream(pathToSave, FileMode.Append);
        long cur_file_size = 0;

        foreach (var file in Files)
        {
           var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);
            cur_file_size += buffer.Length;

            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        fs.Close();
```

Так можно объединить все чанки в текущей и субдиректориях по алфавиту в единый выходной ts. А как выходные файлы нарезать ? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто создавайте новый файл при достижении размера, вы уже считаете размер (что не обязательно, так как `FileStream` тоже считает):

```
string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.ss");
string pathToSave = @"D:\chunks1\" + dateTime + ".ts";
fs = new FileStream(pathToSave, FileMode.Append);

foreach (var file in Files)
{
    var chunk = File.OpenRead(file.FullName);

    if (fs.Position + chunk.Length > 5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) // 5 Gb
    {
        fs.Close(); // закрываем текущий файл

        // создаем новый
        dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.ss");
        pathToSave = @"D:\chunks1\" + dateTime + ".ts";
        fs = new FileStream(pathToSave, FileMode.Append);
    }

    chunk.CopyTo(fs);
    chunk.Close();
}

fs.Close();
```

Comment: Странно, почему бы просто не вызывать `CopyTo` вместо считывания буфера в память?

Comment: @ヒミコ да, так действительно лучше, я поленился сильно менять пример автора вопроса :)